# Efficient image padding in C

Tags: beginner, c, image

I am currently implementing pyramids in Lucas Kanade algorithm for optical flow. To be able to build pyramids, I need to pad the images (mirror edge matrix elements) for the required amount of rows/cols determined by parameter `half_window`.

I have written this code which works but I am new to C programming and it looks overly complex to me. How would an experienced C programmer write this?

`image_t` is a struct for storing image data I am required to use. Rest is my code. It first adjusts sizes of output which is a pointer to `struct image_t` object. Then it builds padded image row by row as follows:

- skip first `half_window` rows
- mirror first `half_window` columns of the row
- copy original elements of that row
- mirror the last `half_window` columns of the row
- skip last `half_window` rows

Then

- mirror first `half_window` rows with `memcpy`
- mirror last `half_window` rows with `memcpy`

```
struct image_t {
  enum image_type type;   // The image type
  uint16_t w;             // Image width
  uint16_t h;             // Image height
  struct timeval ts;      // The timestamp of creation

  uint8_t buf_idx;        // Buffer index for V4L2 freeing
  uint32_t buf_size;      // The buffer size
  void *buf;              // Image buffer (depending on the image_type)
};

void pad_image(struct image_t *input, struct image_t *output, uint8_t half_window)
{
    uint8_t *input_buf = (uint8_t *)input->buf;

    output->h = input->h + 2*half_window;
    output->w = input->w + 2*half_window;
    output->buf_size = sizeof(uint8_t) * output->h * output->w;
    free(output->buf);
    output->buf = malloc(output->buf_size);
    uint8_t *output_buf = (uint8_t*)output->buf;

    for (int i = half_window; i != (output->h-half_window); i++){

        for (int j=0; j!=half_window; j++)
            output_buf[i*output->w + (half_window -1 - j)] = input_buf[(i-half_window)*input->w + j];

        for (int j=half_window; j!=output->w-half_window;j++)
            output_buf[i*output->w + j] = input_buf[(i-half_window)*input->w + (j - half_window)];

        for (int j=0; j!=half_window;j++)
            output_buf[i*output->w + output->w - half_window + j] = output_buf[i*output->w + output->w - half_window -1 - j];
    }

    for (int i=0; i!=half_window; i++){
        memcpy(&output_buf[(half_window-1)*output->w - i*output->w], &output_buf[half_window*output->w + i*output->w], sizeof(uint8_t)*output->w);
        memcpy(&output_buf[(output->h - half_window)*output->w + i*output->w], &output_buf[(output->h-half_window-1)*output->w - i*output->w], sizeof(uint8_t)*output->w);

    }
}
```

Input:

> ```
>    1    2    3    4 
>    5    6    7    8 
>    9   10   11   12 
>   13   14   15   16
> ```

Expected output for `half_window = 2`:

> ```
>    6    5    5    6    7    8    8    7 
>    2    1    1    2    3    4    4    3 
>    2    1    1    2    3    4    4    3 
>    6    5    5    6    7    8    8    7 
>   10    9    9   10   11   12   12   11 
>   14   13   13   14   15   16   16   15 
>   14   13   13   14   15   16   16   15 
>   10    9    9   10   11   12   12   11
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to the code I feel make things more clear, I will post them here in case someone needs something similar.

Code below is used in my function and is work of Freek van Tienen (part of open source software Paparazzi):

```
struct image_t {
  enum image_type type;   ///< The image type
  uint16_t w;             ///< Image width
  uint16_t h;             ///< Image height
  struct timeval ts;      ///< The timestamp of creation

  uint8_t buf_idx;        ///< Buffer index for V4L2 freeing
  uint32_t buf_size;      ///< The buffer size
  void *buf;              ///< Image buffer (depending on the image_type)
};

void image_create(struct image_t *img, uint16_t width, uint16_t height, enum image_type type)
{
  // Set the variables
  img->type = type;
  img->w = width;
  img->h = height;


  // Depending on the type the size differs
  if (type == IMAGE_YUV422) {
    img->buf_size = sizeof(uint8_t) * 2 * width * height;
  } else if (type == IMAGE_JPEG) {
    img->buf_size = sizeof(uint8_t) * 2 * width * height;  // At maximum quality this is enough
  } else if (type == IMAGE_GRADIENT) {
    img->buf_size = sizeof(int16_t) * width * height;
  } else {
    img->buf_size = sizeof(uint8_t) * width * height;
  }

  img->buf = malloc(img->buf_size);
}
```

My code for image padding:

```
void pad_image(struct image_t *input, struct image_t *output, uint8_t expand)
{
    image_create(output, input->w + 2 * expand, input->h + 2 * expand, input->type);

    uint8_t *input_buf = (uint8_t *)input->buf;
    uint8_t *output_buf = (uint8_t *)output->buf;

    // Skip first `expand` rows, iterate through next input->h rows
    for (uint16_t i = expand; i != (output->h - expand); i++){

        // Mirror first `expand` columns
        for (uint8_t j = 0; j != expand; j++)
            output_buf[i * output->w + (expand - 1 - j)] = input_buf[(i - expand) * input->w + j];

        // Copy corresponding row values from input image
        memcpy(&output_buf[i * output->w + expand], &input_buf[(i - expand) * input->w], sizeof(uint8_t) * input->w);

        // Mirror last `expand` columns
        for (uint8_t j = 0; j != expand; j++)
            output_buf[i * output->w + output->w - expand + j] = output_buf[i * output->w + output->w - expand -1 - j];
    }

    // Mirror first `expand` and last `expand` rows
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i != expand; i++){
        memcpy(&output_buf[(expand - 1) * output->w - i * output->w], &output_buf[expand * output->w + i * output->w], sizeof(uint8_t) * output->w);
        memcpy(&output_buf[(output->h - expand) * output->w + i * output->w], &output_buf[(output->h - expand - 1) * output->w - i * output->w], sizeof(uint8_t) * output->w);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? In that case, it is perfectly OK to self-accept your own answer. If it doesn't answer your question, you should possibly close off this entire question, and repost a new question with updated information.